# include javascript file in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an html file(index.html) which calls a php file(pdj.php) via javascipt and populates the output in a div(pdj).  This works.

```
$.ajax({
     url: '../command/pdj.php', 
     type: "POST",
     data: ({xparam: xparam}),
     success: function(data){
         var arraydata = $.parseJSON(data);          
      $("#pdj").html(arraydata[0]); 
     }
});
```

The php file needs a javascript file(spinner.js) to work.

1) Adding the javascipt file in index.html does not use it.

2) Including in pdj.php causes an error
include_once('spinner.js');

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 1
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (pdj.js:40)
    at fire (jquery-3.3.1.js:3268)
```

I am guessing my ajax call is wrong... Can you suggest how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about add   datatype : "application/json", in your ajax call ?

Comment: `include` and `include_once` is there for read and evaluate php code [docs include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) - not javascript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call is not wrong.

> 1) Adding the javascipt file in index.html does not use it.

Problem here is that when the javascript file is executed, it can't find the target because the ajax call is not yet executed which means the DOM object is not yet created for the `spinner.js`.

> 2) Including in pdj.php causes an error include_once('spinner.js');

Here include_once will just add the javascript file's content to the response and this results the broken json and that's why the ajax fails because the content-type is set to `application/json` in you ajax config

The solution is to call the `spinner.js`'s function on ajax success handler.

If you can provide the spinner.js as a link, that would be better for the answer.

```
$.ajax({
     url: '../command/pdj.php', 
     type: "POST",
     data: ({xparam: xparam}),
     success: function(data){
         var arraydata = $.parseJSON(data);          
         $("#pdj").html(arraydata[0]); 
         $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... the spinner.js can be found here [link]https://github.com/shaack/bootstrap-input-spinner/blob/master/src/bootstrap-input-spinner.js

Comment: I have this javascript code which calls the master file:     $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();

Comment: Yeah, call this function on the ajax call success handler

Comment: I tried but got an error     '$.ajax({
         url: '../command/pdj.php', 
         type: "POST",
         data: ({xparam: xparam}),
         success: function(data){
              $.getScript("../js/bootstrap-input-spinner.js");
             var arraydata = $.parseJSON(data);    
          $("#pdj").html(arraydata[0]); 
         }
    });  
'

    $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();

error=:Uncaught TypeError: $(...).inputSpinner is not a function

Comment: formatting looks bad.. but I added an extra line to the success in ajax.. the line was this ' $.getScript("../js/bootstrap-input-spinner.js");' but it did not work.

Comment: Glad to hear it works. Please accept answer helping me :)